# Upload file and receive response on Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: php, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, upload, response

I know how to upload a file to a PHP script to store files to a webserver, and the PHP script generates a unique file name. I want to then use the response from the PHP script with VB, sort of like reading the response. My codes are:

Visual Basic:

```
Sub uploadfile()
    For Each fPath In FilePath
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(fPath, "http://mydomain.com/upload.php")
        MsgBox(fPath)
    Next

End Sub
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "Error";
}else{
    $newfile = uniqid("image_").".".$extension;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "Images/" . $newfile);
}
?>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning VB. Your A-level curriculum would be letting you down if it didn't cover a language that supports a mountain of businesses, whatever you think of its syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself:

```
For Each fPath In FilePath
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Dim responseBinary As Byte()
    responseBinary = client.UploadFile("http://example.com/upload.php", fPath)
    Dim response As String
    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary)
    MsgBox(response)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Researchers
You must use Using

```
For Each fPath In FilePath
    Using client As New WebClient()
        Dim responseBinary As Byte()
        responseBinary = client.UploadFile("http://example.com/upload.php", fPath)
        Dim response As String
        response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary)
        MsgBox(response)
    End Using
Next
```